# How to remove duplicated lines depends from second column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following file:

```
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1   transcript:OIT01734 transcript:OIT01734 1.1e-107    389.8   1000    218 992 1   216 130 345 MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDAR*  MKVWERVVEARVREMTSISVNQFGFMPGRSTTEAIHLVRRLVEHFRDKKKDLHMVFIDLENAYDKVPREVLWRCLEAKSVPEAYIRVIKDMYDGAKTRVRTVGGDSDHFPVVMGLHQGSALSPLLFALVMDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDAPVRIYKSAILGHLNSHGSQNALAGPVEAEENRQKTKKEVMEEIIQKSKFFKAQKAKDREENDELTEQLDKDFTSLVESKALLSLTQPDKINALKALVNKNISVGNVKKDEVADVPRKASIGKEKPDTYEMLVSEMALDMRARPSDRTKTPEEIAQEEKERLELLEQEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDGNASDDNSKLVKDPRTVSGDDLGDDLEEVPRTKLGWIGEILRRKENELESEDAASSGDSDDGEDEGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEEQGKTQTIKDWEQSDDDIIDTELEDDDEGFGDDAKKVVKIKDHKEENLSITVAAENKKKMQVFYGVLLQYFAVLANKKPLNSKLLNLLVKPLMEMSAVSPYFAAICARQRLQRTRAQFCEDLKNTGKSSWPSLKTIFLLRLWSMIFPCSDFRHCVMTPAILLMCEYLMRCTIISGRDIAIASFLCSLLLSVIKQSQKFCPEAIVFIQTLLMAALDRKQRSNSQLDNLMEIKELGPLLCIRSSKVEMDSLDFLTLMDLPEDSQYFHSDNYRTSMLVTVLETLQGFVNVYKELISFPEIFMLISKLLCKMAGENHIPDALREKIKDVSQLIDTKAQEHHMLRQPLKMRKKKPVPIRMLNPKFEENFVKGRDYDPDRERA    389.8   1000    216 85.6    185 31  200 0   0   92.6    0   22IV6AV2SN4IV11IL12GSDA1PS1GE3ED1MK4AV6VF9DE29IV1HQ6FY2MV5FL1EG10IV14CR1HL4KR1KR5QE5PL2KE2GR6FY6GR3 85.6    1.1e-107    99.1
gene.9403.0.4.p1    transcript:OIT35479 transcript:OIT35479 8.5e-191    667.5   1721    690 406 1   378 1   378 MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVLSTCRSFSKSGVPFHSMVVTGGFCQRTQLENLRQELDILIATPGRFMFLIKEGYLQLTNLKCAVLDEVDILFSDEDFETAFQCLINSSPITTQYLFVTATLPMDIYNKLVESFPDCELVSGPGMHRTSPGLEEFLVDCSGDETAEKSPDTAFINKKNALLHLVEDSPVPKTIVFCNKIDSCRKVENALKRFDRKGFSIKILPFHAALDQRRRLANMEEFRRSKMENVSLFLVCTDRASRGIDFEGVDHVVLFDYPRDPSEYVRRVGRTARGAGGKGKAFIFAVGKQVSLARRIMERNKKGHPVHDVPSILT*  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVCQISSSIKGTFATYSPYCSATTHTKRKK  667.5   1721    378 91.0    344 34  352 0   0   93.1    0   6VASP14PQ3VG50IV25PSXPXDXNXNXHXPXPXPXTXQXSXSXSDN38ND3ITAT14DG20DE1KR2FS11GD14IS4QH30DE4EQ1QR2GD102  91.0    8.5e-191    54.8
gene.9403.0.5.p1    transcript:OIT35479 transcript:OIT35479 8.5e-191    667.5   1721    690 406 1   378 1   378 MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVLSTCRSFSKSGVPFHSMVVTGGFCQRTQLENLRQELDILIATPGRFMFLIKEGYLQLTNLKCAVLDEVDILFSDEDFETAFQCLINSSPITTQYLFVTATLPMDIYNKLVESFPDCELVSGPGMHRTSPGLEEFLVDCSGDETAEKSPDTAFINKKNALLHLVEDSPVPKTIVFCNKIDSCRKVENALKRFDRKGFSIKILPFHAALDQRRRLANMEEFRRSKMENVSLFLVCTDRASRGIDFEGVDHVVLFDYPRDPSEYVRRVGRTARGAGGKGKAFIFAVGKQVSLARRIMERNKKGHPVHDVPSILT*  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVCQISSSIKGTFATYSPYCSATTHTKRKK  667.5   1721    378 91.0    344 34  352 0   0   93.1    0   6VASP14PQ3VG50IV25PSXPXDXNXNXHXPXPXPXTXQXSXSXSDN38ND3ITAT14DG20DE1KR2FS11GD14IS4QH30DE4EQ1QR2GD102  91.0    8.5e-191    54.8
gene.69001.9.9.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.4e-294    1011.9  2615    531 530 1   530 1   530 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT* MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  1011.9  2615    530 96.6    512 18  519 0   0   97.9    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM127IT25 96.6    1.4e-294    99.8
gene.9403.9.5.p1    transcript:OIT35479 transcript:OIT35479 8.5e-191    667.5   1721    690 406 1   378 1   378 MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVLSTCRSFSKSGVPFHSMVVTGGFCQRTQLENLRQELDILIATPGRFMFLIKEGYLQLTNLKCAVLDEVDILFSDEDFETAFQCLINSSPITTQYLFVTATLPMDIYNKLVESFPDCELVSGPGMHRTSPGLEEFLVDCSGDETAEKSPDTAFINKKNALLHLVEDSPVPKTIVFCNKIDSCRKVENALKRFDRKGFSIKILPFHAALDQRRRLANMEEFRRSKMENVSLFLVCTDRASRGIDFEGVDHVVLFDYPRDPSEYVRRVGRTARGAGGKGKAFIFAVGKQVSLARRIMERNKKGHPVHDVPSILT*  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVCQISSSIKGTFATYSPYCSATTHTKRKK  667.5   1721    378 91.0    344 34  352 0   0   93.1    0   6VASP14PQ3VG50IV25PSXPXDXNXNXHXPXPXPXTXQXSXSXSDN38ND3ITAT14DG20DE1KR2FS11GD14IS4QH30DE4EQ1QR2GD102  91.0    8.5e-191    54.8
```

The above file has some IDs which are similar

```
gene.9403.0.4.p1
gene.9403.0.5.p1
gene.9403.9.5.p1
```

By remaining only `gene.9403` the IDs become identically. The remaining colums of `gene.9403` are identically and therefore I would like to remove any duplicates.

I used `awk -F"\t" '!seen[$2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7,$8, $9,$10,$11,$12, $13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31]++' select-results2.txt` and it gave me the proper output for the above example

```
chr11_pilon3.g3568.t1   transcript:OIT01734 transcript:OIT01734 1.1e-107    389.8   1000    218 992 1   216 130 345 MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDA    MDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIILIDETRAGVSERLEIWRQTLESKGFKISRSKTEYLECKFGDEPSGVGREVMLGSQAIAKRDSVRYLGSVIQGDGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKIPHKLKGKFFRAMVRPAMFYEAECWPVKNSHIQRMKVAEMRMLRWMCGHTRLDKIKNEVIRQKVGVAPVDKKMGEARLRWFGHVRRRGPDAR*  MKVWERVVEARVREMTSISVNQFGFMPGRSTTEAIHLVRRLVEHFRDKKKDLHMVFIDLENAYDKVPREVLWRCLEAKSVPEAYIRVIKDMYDGAKTRVRTVGGDSDHFPVVMGLHQGSALSPLLFALVMDALTRHIQGDVPWCMLFADDIVLIDETRVGVNERLEVWRQTLESKGFKLSRSKTEYLECKFSAESSEVGRDVKLGSQVIAKRDSFRYLGSVIQGEGEIDGDVTHRIGAGWSKWRLASGVLCDKKVPQKLKGKFYRAVVRPAMLYGAECWPVKNSHVQRMKVAEMRMLRWMRGLTRLDRIRNEVIREKVGVALVDEKMREARLRWYGHVRRRRPDAPVRIYKSAILGHLNSHGSQNALAGPVEAEENRQKTKKEVMEEIIQKSKFFKAQKAKDREENDELTEQLDKDFTSLVESKALLSLTQPDKINALKALVNKNISVGNVKKDEVADVPRKASIGKEKPDTYEMLVSEMALDMRARPSDRTKTPEEIAQEEKERLELLEQEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDGNASDDNSKLVKDPRTVSGDDLGDDLEEVPRTKLGWIGEILRRKENELESEDAASSGDSDDGEDEGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEEQGKTQTIKDWEQSDDDIIDTELEDDDEGFGDDAKKVVKIKDHKEENLSITVAAENKKKMQVFYGVLLQYFAVLANKKPLNSKLLNLLVKPLMEMSAVSPYFAAICARQRLQRTRAQFCEDLKNTGKSSWPSLKTIFLLRLWSMIFPCSDFRHCVMTPAILLMCEYLMRCTIISGRDIAIASFLCSLLLSVIKQSQKFCPEAIVFIQTLLMAALDRKQRSNSQLDNLMEIKELGPLLCIRSSKVEMDSLDFLTLMDLPEDSQYFHSDNYRTSMLVTVLETLQGFVNVYKELISFPEIFMLISKLLCKMAGENHIPDALREKIKDVSQLIDTKAQEHHMLRQPLKMRKKKPVPIRMLNPKFEENFVKGRDYDPDRERA    389.8   1000    216 85.6    185 31  200 0   0   92.6    0   22IV6AV2SN4IV11IL12GSDA1PS1GE3ED1MK4AV6VF9DE29IV1HQ6FY2MV5FL1EG10IV14CR1HL4KR1KR5QE5PL2KE2GR6FY6GR3 85.6    1.1e-107    99.1
gene.9403.0.4.p1    transcript:OIT35479 transcript:OIT35479 8.5e-191    667.5   1721    690 406 1   378 1   378 MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQV  MLSAPRVSPPAVAVAAPARFKFPNVCVNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIIWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTPXXXXXXXXXXXXXDEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHNKHNIADASSRSSFSSYNEPDQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLDDKKNFQKLIRVEDEDRGIAIENVSKHFAGYSIDSHAQSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKRDEIFRERQNLGDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVLSTCRSFSKSGVPFHSMVVTGGFCQRTQLENLRQELDILIATPGRFMFLIKEGYLQLTNLKCAVLDEVDILFSDEDFETAFQCLINSSPITTQYLFVTATLPMDIYNKLVESFPDCELVSGPGMHRTSPGLEEFLVDCSGDETAEKSPDTAFINKKNALLHLVEDSPVPKTIVFCNKIDSCRKVENALKRFDRKGFSIKILPFHAALDQRRRLANMEEFRRSKMENVSLFLVCTDRASRGIDFEGVDHVVLFDYPRDPSEYVRRVGRTARGAGGKGKAFIFAVGKQVSLARRIMERNKKGHPVHDVPSILT*  MLSAPRAPPPAVAVAAPARFKFQNVCGNPVNLLLLHRNVGSSCKRVVVSTKAAYSRMPMDTPGAYQLIDKESGDKFIVWGGTEDDDSSIPSKEVLSWKPLASTSPDNNHPPPTQSSSNEASTRGLTGNFGRLKFRRMRDLVRKSYTKNKERDVIDHDKHNTTDASSRSSFSSYNEPGQLKEQQTLSLPRGRAKIQQLEDRKNSQKLIRVEDEDRDIAIENVSKHFAGYSSDSHAHSARVVHPGSKASASPLRGWGGGSSHYSLKREEIFRQRRNLDDENNFFSRKSFQELGCSDYMIESLRNQHFVRPSHIQAMTFGPIIAGKSCIISDQSGSGKTLAYLLPLIQRLRQEELQGLSKPSSQSPRVVVLAPTAELASQVCQISSSIKGTFATYSPYCSATTHTKRKK  667.5   1721    378 91.0    344 34  352 0   0   93.1    0   6VASP14PQ3VG50IV25PSXPXDXNXNXHXPXPXPXTXQXSXSXSDN38ND3ITAT14DG20DE1KR2FS11GD14IS4QH30DE4EQ1QR2GD102  91.0    8.5e-191    54.8
gene.69001.9.9.p1   NisylKD955766g0010.1    NisylKD955766g0010.1    1.4e-294    1011.9  2615    531 530 1   530 1   530 MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFHNPLSIGSSSHMDVTRLNSMGGTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLHMISENESNNWISGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQMSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASEIFGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKIEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGHRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQEQWKKAFTNCFLMVDDEVGGTGNHEAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPTALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRAIQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT* MKEMCLAVAPLPFRLGNNLIFRNPPSIGSSSHMDATRLNSMGDTTTSLYAESAEKDLSDTVSSSRSEGVPLLPMISENDRNNWIAGDAVVRESEDDEILSLDGDQVSCSLSVVSDSSSLCGDDFIGFEVASDIYGQNFVDAEKSICSVELIAKPGDLVESGVEDDNVSKPFAVKLEEQITDGSSSKSSQVVVQLPLNKGLSAAVSRSVFEVDYIPLWGFTSVCGRRPEMEDALATVPRFLRIPLQMLVGDRVPDGVSRCLSHLTAHFFGVYDGHGGSQVANYCRDRVHAVLAEELEKFMANLNDESIRQNCQDQWKKAFTNCFLKVDDEVGGTGNREAVAAETVGSTAVVAIVCSSHIIVANCGDSRAVLCRGKEPMALSVDHKPNREDEYARIEAAGGKVIQWNGHRVFGVLAMSRSIGDRYLKPWIIPDPEVMFIPRTKDDECLILASDGLWDVMSNEEACELARKRILLWHKKNGVTLTLERGQGIDPAAQAAAECLSNRATQKGSKDNITVIVVDLKAQRKFKSKT  1011.9  2615    530 96.6    512 18  519 0   0   97.9    0   21HR2LP9VA7GD29HP5EDSR4SA20MV25ED1FY40IL74HD62ED11MK10HR40TM127IT25 96.6    1.4e-294    99.8
```

However, I am concern that if I do not consider `gene.9403` I might remove wrong entries. Is there a way to consider also the first column?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Providing lines with a thousand characters each just obfuscates your question.

Comment: Is this a different question from the one at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64779019/1745001? Or are you reposting this one that was closed - https://stackoverflow.com/q/64777179/1745001?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```bsh
awk '
  {line = gensub(/^([^.]+\.[^.]+)[^[:blank:]]*/, "\1", 1, $0)}
  !seen[line]++
' file
```

Comment: Yes. Bad edit on my part. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You should probably mention that requires an awk that supports gensub(), e.g. GNU awk.